# Use Tor browser as non-root Linux

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, linux, ubuntu, debian

If I want to use the Tor browser as a non root user is there a way to do it without having to completely logout of the root workspace and log back in as another user?

Basically have the browser run without root privileges?

Using Debian/Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run any command as a different user using `sudo`:

```
sudo -u my_user tor-browser-en
```

If you need to use multiple commands you can do [this](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/9b409243533551993989910721dfb85a8b2d1868/.bash_history#L1689-L1699):

```
sudo -u my_user sh -c "first && second"
```

---

If you want to background the application, you should *not* do this (it will only work as expected if you're already authenticated with `sudo`):

```
sudo -u my_user tor-browser-en & # Don't do this
```

but rather this:

```
sudo -u my_user sh -c 'tor-browser-en &'
```

The latter will ensure that you're asked for the `sudo` password *before* the browser is run in the background.

Comment: Here's a stupid question... how do I set it up so I can run "tor-browser-en" in the command line?  Is there an apt-get way to download?  I've looked but haven't seen one...

Comment: You might want to check/ask on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) - I don't use a Debian derivative distro myself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but I kept getting permission errors. This is how I fixed it (it's a permissions issue):

Add a new user

```
adduser <username>
```

Make sure a home directory exists for that user

```
mkdir /home/<username>
```

On the root account, copy the tor folder containing the executable you downloaded to the home folder for the non-root user:

```
mv ~/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-9.0.9_en-US.tar.xz /home/<username>/
```

Change the permissions like so:

```
chown -R <username>:/home/<username>
```

To give the ownership of that folder to the non-root account. Then you'll be able to unzip/execute whatever you want in that folder as the non-root user. Hope that helps!